# Permission denied on sudo remove

Tags: linux, sudo, rm, sudoers

I have two users userA and userB. userA has permission over a file named `cache`. I want to give permission to userB to remove the file. I have made following entry in `/etc/sudoers` file :

```
userB ALL=(userA) NOPASSWD:/bin/rm /opt/cache
```

When I type `sudo -u userA /bin/rm /opt/cache`, it says permission denied. However cache has `777` permission. Please let me know where I am doing it wrong.

Comment: Usually `/opt/cache` is a directory (I see you edited "directory" to "file" but I'm not sure why?). You need `rm -r` to remove a directory. Also you may get weird errors if `/opt/cache` is a mount point. Are you using SELinux, by chance?

Comment: cache is a file in my case. I mistakenly typed directory there and I am not using SELinux. Also, it's not a mount point. For more clarity please find output of ll : `-rwxrwxrwx.  1 userA userA     87475 Jun 17 06:39 cache`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NOPASSWD` takes a comma separated list of programs. Do this instead:

```
userB ALL=(userA) NOPASSWD:/bin/rm
```

Note that will allow userB to delete *any* file that userA can delete.

A better, more controlled solution might be to change the owner group of that file to some group that is allowed to delete it, then add the users to that group.

You might also get away with a shell script that deletes that file, and specifying that instead. Not sure though, and take care to ensure that only root or userA can edit that script.